# Searching with Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, string, hash

I am using a hash containing 5000 items to match words in a sentence, it so occurs that when I match for eg: `if($hash{$word}){Do Something}` sometimes it happens that the period occurs in the word and even if it is a match the presence of period results in a non-match. Can anything be done to ignore any punctuations when matching with hashes?

Comment: You need to consider situations like `O'Malley` and decide if the embedded quote is punctuation or not.  When you've come up with a set of rules that you like, then apply them to the input words to eliminate everything that's not punctuation before looking them up in the hash.

Comment: @Jim I am also thinking on those lines but the problem is that I need the periods for the sake of sentence boundary detection in after the matching so I cannot remove any punctuation marks in the sentence.

Comment: Can you provide more sample code?  The solution may be in how you are parsing your words or it may be in how you populate the hash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to redefine the words you look up to exclude the punctuation, remembering that you might or might not want to eliminate all punctuation (for example, you might want to keep dashes and apostrophes - but not single quotes).

The crude technique - not recognizing any punctuation is:

```
$key = $word;
$key ~= s/\W//g;  # Any non-word characters are removed
if (defined $hash{$key}) { DoSomething; }
```

You can refine the substitute command to meet your needs.

But the only way to make sure that the hash keys match is to make sure that the hashed key matches - so you need to be consistent with what you supply.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $s = $word;
$s =~ s/\W//g;
my $k;
for (keys %hash){
    s/\W//g;
    if($_ eq $s){
        $k = $_;
        last;
    }
}
if(defined $k){
    # Do Something
}
```